# Add a global rule for HeavisideTheta[0]

Tags: rule

I would like to define `HeavisideTheta[0]` and `HeavisideTheta[0.]` (as apparently Mathematica won't recognize these two as identical) to be always in my notebook identically equal to `1`. What would be a quick and clean way to do this instead of constantly having to add rules in my code?

Comment: Is it even possible to change the values of a built in function in Mathematica?

Comment: Well if I tell Mathematica to apply the rule to an expression, i.e. `/.HeavisideTheta[0]-> 1` it manages to do that. @MauricioLobos

Comment: I'd suggest to define a new function with the desired behaviour. You could re-define the existing one with `Unprotect` and then `Protect`, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Does `$Assumptions = HeavisideTheta[0] == 1` and `HeavisideTheta[0] // Simplify` work for you?

Comment: @MauricioLobos Assumptions doesn't work. Simplify works but not with `HeavisideTheta[0.]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global assumption for a notebook might be an option

```
$Assumptions = HeavisideTheta[0] == 1 && HeavisideTheta[0.] == 1;
HeavisideTheta[0]
HeavisideTheta[0] // Simplify
HeavisideTheta[0.]
HeavisideTheta[0.] // Simplify
```

[image]