# How to set HeavisideTheta[0] to 1 permanently

Tags: packages

I always meet the `HeavisideTheta[0] = 1` during my work, every time I need to use the function `Replace[]` to finish the job, which has been harassing me. So I want to know if there's a method to set `HeavisideTheta[0] = 1` permanently, or copy the definition of `HeavisideTheta` to a new file and rewrite it to a new package(.m or .wl file) meeting my will. In the post [Add a global rule for HeavisideTheta[0]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132595/add-a-global-rule-for-heavisidetheta0), Mauricio Fernández proposed a global assumption method, but it is not convenient because I have to call the `Simplify` everytime. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `Unprotect[HeavisideTheta]`, `HeavisideTheta[0]=1`, `Protect[HeavisideTheta]` as suggested in one of the comments in the linked question? That would be the usual way to do this, if you had to. Beware that it might break things, though.

Comment: The question arises: what for?

Comment: Maybe use [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) instead?

Comment: @user64494 @Chip Hurst, I use the `HeavisideTheta` to control  boundary condition during symbolic formula derivation and the final numerical calculation, which involving Heaviside's derivative and `HeavisideTheta[0]`, so `Unitstep` doesn't meet the situation.

Comment: @Carl Lange, thanks, the method you talked about is feasible, can you tell me how to write this code fragment into init.m file and make every .nb file load them automatically every time?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I've never done that, and I also think it may not be very safe to do! You should be able to find some example on this site or in the documentation, though.

Comment: @Carl Lange, I have write the code fragment into the init.m in the directory of C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel, and realized what I wanted. In the end, I want to know, what is "Beware that it might break things" you talked?  Can you provide me with some detail information or live example? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any real details - I am personally worried about changing parts of the internal WL system without really knowing what they might do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can set this by `Unprotect`ing the symbol, like so:

```
Unprotect[HeavisideTheta]
HeavisideTheta[0]=1
Protect[HeavisideTheta]
```

Note that this may cause some issues with functions that expect `HeavisideTheta[0]` to be `0`.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken your solution, write `Unprotect[HeavisideTheta];
HeavisideTheta[0]=1;HeavisideTheta[0.0]=1;
Protect[HeavisideTheta];` into  the init.m in the directory of C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel, and realized what I wanted.