# Correcting HeavisideTheta in MM11.3 for generating the same results with UnitStep in MM5.2

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, compatibility, generalized-function

The `UnitStep` was replaced with the `HeavisideTheta` after the version 6.0 ([reference here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195465/which-version-of-mathematica-did-diracdelta-become-to-the-derivative-of-heavisid)), but some differences confused me between the old and the new version as the follows (For convenience, the f[x] is simplified). I want to know how to correct the `HeavisideTheta` in the Mathematica V11.3 for  generating the same results with `UnitStep` in MM5.2. For the problem, I have proposed some methods( [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209225/how-to-call-an-old-build-in-function-in-a-new-version-of-mathematica) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219164/how-to-use-the-old-kernel-in-a-newer-version-of-mma)), but which didn't give the result I want. Thanks.

Code in V11.3

```
f[x_] := 1;
Integrate[f[x]*HeavisideTheta[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
Integrate[f[x]*HeavisideTheta[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
Integrate[f[x]*D[HeavisideTheta[x], x], {x, 0, ∞}]
Integrate[
 f[x]*D[HeavisideTheta[x], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Code in V5.2

```
f[x_]:=1;
Integrate[f[x]*UnitStep[x],{x,0,∞}]
Integrate[f[x]*UnitStep[x],{x,-∞,∞}]
Integrate[f[x]*D[UnitStep[x],x],{x,0,∞}]
Integrate[f[x]*D[UnitStep[x],x],{x,-∞,∞}]
```

**The results in V11.3**

[image]

**The results in V5.2**

[image]

Comment: In 3rd example, what you need seems to be `HeavisideTheta[0] == 1/2`, but you mentioned you want `HeavisideTheta[0]` to be `1` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195367/1871). Does your goal change? Or this is a special case?

Comment: BTW, it's worth mentioning that the behavior of `UnitStep` in _v5.2_ is inconsistent, `f[Infinity] UnitStep[Infinity] - f[0] UnitStep[0] - Integrate[f'[x] UnitStep[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` gives `0`.

Comment: @xzczd, Thanks for your attention. I wanted `HeavisideTheta[0]` to be 1, because `UnitStep[0]=1` in V5.2 (you can check it through the help document of V5.2), I just want to realize the function of  `UnitStep` in V5.2 by using the `HeavisideTheta` inV11.3 (`HeavisideTheta`, no value in 0 point). But today, this time, the 3rd example show us that `HeavisideTheta[0]` should be 1/2, they will give the same result. In a word, on the one hand, `HeavisideTheta[0]` should be 1 because `UnitStep[0]=1` in V5.2, on the other hand, `HeavisideTheta[0]` should be 1/2 because the 3rd example.

Comment: Well, as pointed out in my last comment, the design of `UnitStep` in _v5.2_ is self-contradictory. If your legacy code has made use of such feature, then things become a little troublesome. It's not too hard to find work-around for this 4 examples, but I doubt if the solution can be extended to more general cases. Do you have something, say,  a complete summarization of the feature of `UnitStep` in _v5.2_? Or perhaps you can show a bigger example indicating what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @xzczd can you sent an email to likeleetemp(AT)gmail(DOT)com ? I want to sent my code's file to your email, it's not convenient to paste here because the codes are too large.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's my stupid insistence that I only discuss _Mathematica_ in public. And, honestly speaking, I'm not in the mood to solve extremely localized problem, either.

Comment: Just checked in _v5.0_, the first 2 examples all give `Integrate::idiv` warning and return unevaluated so I can't check further, but I wonder what's the output of `Integrate[-UnitStep[x],{x,0,∞}]` and `Integrate[-UnitStep[x],{x,-∞,∞}]` in _v5.2_?

Comment: @xzczd, thanks. `Integrate[-UnitStep[x],{x,0,∞}]` gives `-∞`  , and `Integrate[-UnitStep[x],{x,-∞,∞}]` gives `Integrate::idiv: Integral of UnitStep[x] does not converge on {-∞,∞}, -∞`. Hope it helps you find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my work-around. Not sure if it can be applied to your real problem, but it can at least help you to construct a sample closer to your real problem, I think.

We define the following 2 functions:

```
ClearAll[unitStep, v52]

SetAttributes[v52, HoldAll]
v52[expr_Integrate] := 
 Check[expr /. HeavisideTheta[0] -> 1/2, ∞ NIntegrate @@ Unevaluated@expr // 
   Quiet, Integrate::idiv]

SetAttributes[unitStep, Listable]
unitStep[x_?NumericQ] = UnitStep[x];
unitStep[x_] = HeavisideTheta[x];
```

`v52` is a function **only** for `Integrate[…]`, once `idiv` warning is generated, it replaces the output with `±∞`, and any `HeavisideTheta[0]` generated by `Integrate` will be replaced by `1/2`.

`unitStep` is equivalent to `UnitStep` for numeric inputs, and equivalent to `HeavisideTheta` for symbolic inputs.

Some examples:

```
unitStep[{-1, 1, 0}]
(* {0, 1, 1} *)

unitStep'[x]
(* DiracDelta[x] *)

v52@Integrate[f[x] unitStep[x], {x, 0, ∞}]

(* Integrate::idiv *)
(* ∞ *)

v52@Integrate[-f[x] unitStep[x], {x, 0, ∞}]

(* Integrate::idiv *)
(* -∞ *)

v52@Integrate[f[x] unitStep[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* Integrate::idiv *)
(* ∞ *)

v52@Integrate[-f[x] unitStep[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* Integrate::idiv *)
(* -∞ *)

v52@Integrate[f[x] D[unitStep[x], x], {x, 0, ∞}]
(* 1/2 *)

v52@Integrate[f[x] D[unitStep[x], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.