# Why does HeavisideTheta give different value at the point 0 and 0.?

Tags: heavisidetheta

As the following figure described, why does HeavisideTheta give different value at the point 0 and 0.? Especially at the coordinate origin, one gives the value 1 and another 0 when HeavisideTheta[0]=0. Isn't 0 and 0. the same point?

Note: DiracDelta gives similar result at 0 and 0. as the following figure.

Thanks!

```
$Version

Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0, Infinity}]
Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0., Infinity}]

Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0, Infinity}] /. 
 HeavisideTheta[0] -> 0
Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0., Infinity}] /. 
 HeavisideTheta[0.] -> 0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that `Integrate[DiracDelta[z], {z, 0, Infinity}]` and `Integrate[DiracDelta[z], {z, 0., Infinity}]` give the same results. So it might be that this behavior is a consequence of how `DiracDelta` handles exact vs. numerical inputs.

Comment: `HeavisideTheta` is an implementation of the antiderivative of $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica. This is a distribution too and the integral `Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0, Infinity}]` makes no sense in traditional math (e.g, see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Distribution+%28mathematics%29&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) for info). `HeavisideTheta[0]` is an invetion of Mathematica developers, not a math notion.

Comment: @Michael Seifert, Thanks. A description has been added based on your comments.

Comment: @user64494, Thanks. Why [Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) gives different values at the point 0 at the [website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)?

Comment: @likehust: As [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html?q=DiracDelta) says "Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points:" and gives an  (incorrect) example `NIntegrate[DiracDelta[x],  {x, -2, 1}]`. As I know it, most of  applications of distributions lie in ODEs and PDEs and don't require any integration.

Comment: @user64494: The documentation says "H(0) = 0 is used when H needs to be left-continuous. In this case H is an indicator function of an open semi-infinite interval", this is just I want. I can not figure out they how to use the value. Thank you.

Comment: Concerning the liked by you Wiki page, "This page was last edited on 1 November 2023, at 09:13 (UTC)" . This page is often edited and its references are not solid.

Comment: @likehust: I repeat the support of `HeavisideTheta` is `0` and `HeavisideTheta[0]` makes no sense. The developers wrongly  change `HeavisideTheta` by a usual function `UnitStep`. That's all.

Comment: @user64494, Thanks, You are an authority in this field. Plus, can you help me study the method about the heaviside in the [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0165212587900448), Thank you very much.

Comment: @likehust: You wrote "Plus, can you help me study the method about the heaviside in the article". Unfortunately, I am not a specialist in this field.

Comment: I'd say it's just the current design of `HeavisideTheta`. Probably there won't be a simple solution like setting an option or turning to another built-in function (you're looking for something like this, right?) I believe the easiest solution is coding a function that behaves as expected all by oneself (as I've done under [this question of yours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221766/1871) ).

Comment: @xzczd, Thank you very much. You are right. I will use a user-defined function to deal with the real problem based on your suggestion in the future. Thanks again.